# When creating a navbar in bootstrap 3, I cannot seem to get the buttons to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am creating a website with a navbar. I want the navbar to go all the way accross the screen at 100 percent width, but I need the buttons to be centered.
Here is my html code:

```
<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">                           
<ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
<li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">NEWS</a></li>                                           
<li class = "dropdown">

 <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">MEDIA <b class = "caret"></b></a>
 <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href = "#">MUSIC</a></li>
 <li><a href = "#">VIDEO</a></li>
 <li><a href = "#">PICTURES</a></li>                                                     
 </ul>                                          
</li>
<li><a href = "#">SHOWS</a></li>
 <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>

  </ul> 

  </div>
```

and my css code:

```
 .nav{
 margin-top: 63px;
 height:80px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 border-width:1px 0;
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
//position:left;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-top: 63px;
 padding:0;
 text-align:center;
 background-color: #333;
 width:100%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 }

.navbar .navbar-nav{
display:inline-block;
float: none;
}

.nav li{
 text-align: center;
 padding:15px;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 3px;
 margin-left:10px;
 font-size: 20px; 
 }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

I think it must be an easy css fix but I can only seem to center the whole navbar not just the button links. Any help would be great thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/ZguC7/362/ codelink

Update:
Now that I changed the

```
.nav li{ 
 float: none;
 display:inline-block;
  }
```

The buttons now center, but when the navbar collapses the navbutton displays horizontally not vertically like it should. Any suggestion on how to solve both problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float` on the `li` elements and use `display: inline-block`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZguC7/363/)**

The reason this was not centering (even though `.nav` has `text-align: center`) for you was that the `li` elements were floating `left`, which will make the element ignore `text-align`.

```
.nav li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: But now when it collapses it is not vertical any more, the button is horizontal.

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out, i added @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: left;
    } To display horzontialy when it is in mobile mode. I think that about fixed it.